# Jumble Solver url rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to do the followings:

1. Every url will be non www version.
   So, when someone will search
   https://www.englishact.com/DifferentLiterature/

   It will be automatically redirected to

   https://englishact.com/DifferentLiterature/
2. Url will ignore index.php

   Example:

   https://www.englishact.com/jumblesolver/index.php

   will be redirected to

   https://englishact.com/jumblesolver/

Problem 1 solved. Need to edit second condition (2)

This is my current htaccess code

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule https://www.englishact.com/jumblewordsolver/index.php https://englishact.com/jumblewordsolver/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: ok. so? what's the problem?

Comment: My htaccess code is not perfect. Need some edit. Could you help me?

Comment: First problem solved by this code:

Comment: RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: well, looks like you're capable enough of solving this yourself. besides that, I still don't know what your problem is, and I'm too lazy to run your code to find out myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /index.php to /
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.php$ https://englishact.com/$1 [NC,L,R=301] 

# Redirect without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```